# How to resize uiimageview in tableviewcell that is aspect fit?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to resize the `UIImageView` to the exact image size of the `aspectfitmode` without the extra space that comes with the aspectfit mode.

Also how can i do this resizing so that it wont make it glitchy when showing the images in `UITableViewCells`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the UIImageView's height constraint as the IBOutLet Property and then calculate the aspect ratio scaled height of the UIImage. Based on that set the constraint constant.

```
float ratio = SCREEN_WIDTH / width;
float scaledHeight = height * ratio;
//float scaledWidth = width * ratio; uncomment if required

//Should not exceed the Screen size to make the image visible at a time without scrolling.
if (scaledHeight > SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
scaledHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
}

cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = scaledHeight;
```

Comment: what is cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant?

Comment: It is the UIImageView height constraint IBOutlet

Comment: yeah i figured it out, and when i set the imageHeightConstraint, not all the cells get updated untill i scroll the table.

Comment: You should use this code inside willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method . Did it resolve your problem?

Comment: Should i then load my images in willDisplayCell? instead of cellforrow?

Comment: If it is the helpful answer do accept and upvote dear. :)

Comment: so you recommend doing it in willDisplay?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ABC.jpg"];
[imageView setImage:img];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y,
                             img.size.width, img.size.height);
```